# How to fix random 'End' key press events in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xorg, events

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series laptop. I get random 'End' Key Press events. If I am browsing a web page, it randomly scrolls down to the end of the page(as if the 'End' key is pressed).

I used evtest to check for the events that I am getting. I ran it and then selected `event4` for monitoring keyboard events.

[image]

My terminal is filled with `KEY_END` events. Attaching a screenshot.
[image]

This issue occurs randomly. I have disabled `End` key of my laptop by commenting the keycode corresponding to `End` key in the file /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev. `End` key is disabled from laptop but evtest still shows the events and annoyingly web pages keep scrolling down.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue but for me, it page up. scrolling the page upwards